# Vertical centering in a drawer on all devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good afternoon,

I am trying to center an image button vertically inside a drawer (for the test I am using a black box). I have managed to center the box horizontally, but I have tried everything, but could not center it vertically. I was able to center it once, but on the phone it would not be centered anymore, or when I change orientation of the screen. So what I want is to always display box in the vertical middle of the drawer, no matter what is the orientation or screen size.

The entire page is here: https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~cm3283/MobileVer/index.html

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add a style to parent of black box:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
```

Comment: Thank you, it is way closer to what I want now. But In my case it goes a little lower, than middle. Is it because the top left corner is centered in the middle, not the center of the image? 
Thank you in advance.

P. S. I have updated the page, so you can see what I mean

Comment: @ЧингизМарданов you can always adjust positioning with more percents. So if 50% is not good for you use something different. For what you have now it is best to use. 
`.drawerContent {
    position: relative;
    top: 35%;
}`